# Forgetting a VM in Vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I've started a VM on Google Compute Engine using Vagrant with the `vagrant-google` provider. I no longer wish to control the VM using Vagrant, but I would like it to keep running without me interrupting it.

What's the proper way to have Vagrant "forget" about this machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the instance has been installed on GCE and you can control directly from there.

Locally you can delete the `.vagrant` folder that vagrant created in the folder when you launch it

After this to remove references you can run `vagrant global-status --prune` which will remove invalid entries and clean vagrant conf file from this machine